# Haskell: Find tuple with first element x in list of tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples

Allow me to explain if my question is not clear. Let's say I have `tuples :: [(a, Int)]`. I have created this using `zip`. Now, I want to find a corresponding `Int` value for my `a` element. I'm trying to figure out how I do this.

`f :: [(a, Int)] -> a -> Int`

Above is the type of the function I need.

Or how it needs to be used in ghci:

`let tuples = zip ['a','b','c'] [1..]`

`f tuples 'a'`

returns: `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

in the Prelude. It returns a `Maybe` because the item you're looking up might not be in the list.

But you didn't ask for safety and the argument order is different from what you asked, so it doesn't answer your question *exactly*.

Comment: The argument order was just an example, that works great, thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Aside: in case you don't know it already, this is fun for discovering existing functions based on their (approximate) type signature: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could search on hoogle for type signatures, that's very useful to know!

Comment: Wow thank you !! Is there an equivalent function to lookup from `b` ?

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer says, you may wish to use `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b` ([source-code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#lookup)). You may implement it in point-free style as `lookup key = fmap snd . safeHead . filter ((== key) . fst)`.

To drop the safety when the key is not present on the list, just swap `safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a` with `head :: [a] -> a`, and to change the parameter order simply `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`.

Therefore, to find your initial specification we could have:

```
myLookup :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> b
myLookup = flip myLookup'
    where myLookup' key = snd . head . filter ((== key) . fst)
```